# How To setKeepScreenOn()

Tags: android

How can I reference the `Activity` `View` from within the `onCreate()` method so I can use `view.setKeepScreenOn()`.

Comment: See this link : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `android:keepScreenOn` in your layout xml to have it set automatically when your layout is inflated. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:keepScreenOn).

Answer (score 3):

You can get a specific view defined in your xml file like:

```
   View view = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```