# How do I keep the screen on in my App?

Tags: android

For my Android app I never want the phone to lock or the back light to turn off

Comment: There is a better solution in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807634/disable-keep-screen-on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16015358/1318946

Comment: this duplicated question got more views and I guess it's because older question used _force_ but here _keep_

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use **PowerManager.WakeLock** class inorder to perform this.
See the following code:

```
import android.os.PowerManager;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* This code together with the one in onDestroy() 
         * will make the screen be always on until this Activity gets destroyed. */
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        this.mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.mWakeLock.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Use the follwing permission in manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Hope this will solve your problem...:)

Comment: Shouldn't this be in `onResuem` and `onPause` so the app won't keep the screen on when user hits the home button?

Comment: Does PowerManager pm have to be declared as final?

Comment: Not so good proposal for what @SethHikari asked.. Too much work, too much cpu power consumed..

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, another answer with lower ratings (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14926037/498949) works just as well and doesn't rely on you releasing the wakelock.

Comment: This method is deprecated, you can refer to the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK

Comment: Please remove this answer, which is obsolete. Thank you.

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT USE A WAKE LOCK**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2134602/119527).

Comment: I don't think the answer should be removed, just edited to state that it's deprecated and that it's best to simply use a `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag.

Comment: **It is deprecated**. You can just add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` on XML file or add `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` on onCreate Activity. [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen)

Comment: Do not delete this answer. There are a few cases where getWindow().addFlags(FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) does not work as intention.

Comment: @Naetmul Can you give us some example?

Comment: @FedericoPonzi Case 1: When you need only SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, not SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK. Case 2: When you need screen wake lock while another developer's app is running in the foreground, where you cannot directly get the Window of that app.

Comment: @interlude why remove it? It's still useful for niche applications.

Answer (score 245):

Add one line of code after setContentView() in onCreate()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flag);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Comment: This answer is per activity, much better suitable if you don't want app to wake cpu because u didn't manage wake locks properly..

Comment: So how do you turn this flag off?

Comment: @kilaka turn it off with the line `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)`.

Comment: @anthonycr I assume it gets reset automatically when the activity is destroyed, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, it will be reset automatically. See the note in the "Keep the Screen On" section: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Answer (score 130):

Lots of answers already exist here! I am answering this question with additional and reliable solutions:

Using `PowerManager.WakeLock` is not so reliable a solution, as the app requires additional permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Also, if it accidentally remains holding the wake lock, it can leave the screen on.

So, I recommend not using the `PowerManager.WakeLock` solution. Instead of this, use any of the following solutions:

**First:**

We can use `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);    
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
```

---

**Second:**

we can use `keepScreenOn`

**1.** implementation using `setKeepScreenOn()` in java code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.driver_home, null);// or any View (incase generated programmatically ) 
        v.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        setContentView(v);
       }
```

Docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn(boolean)

**2.** Adding `keepScreenOn` to xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >
```

Docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3akeepScreenOn

**Notes (some useful points):**

1. It doesn't matter that `keepScreenOn` should be used on a Main/Root/Parent View. It can be used with any child view and will work the same way it works in a parent view.
2. The only thing that matters is that the view's visibility must be visible. Otherwise, it will not work!

Comment: Yes, it should be the correct answer! I was seeking for an example of an implementation of "keepScreeOn" (which I thought it was the best way to do this) and this is the only answer that shows it well!

Comment: no need for the permission .

Comment: v.setKeepScreenOn(true);    Wonderfully works on M sdk phones, didn't check on Ls'

Comment: Good explanation

Comment: For the **Second** solution, we don't steps **1** *and* **2**. Just using step **2** was enough for me.

Comment: android:keepScreenOn="true"  was enough for me for exoplayer

Answer (score 57):

**Don't Use Wake Lock.**

```
It requires permission and other stuff and may cause error if you forget to set it in right time.
```

The easiest way is to use the below code when you want to keep your screen on..

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

One addition to the answer if you want to remove or terminate keep_Screen_on

```
getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

you can also see [here](http://blog.blundellapps.com/tut-keep-screen-onawake-3-possible-ways/)..

And `the best and easiest way` .. Using  `android:keepScreenOn="true"`  in layout root of your activity does the same thing without extra code. But it will remain it in Keep_Scree_on State..

It can be vary on your demand [**See here**](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

Comment: Works great. I also clear the flag in onStop so screen on state behaves as usual when outside my app. For some odd reason it seemed to work without doing that but seems to be the correct way to do it anyway so to be sure I'll leave it (perhaps it works differently on other phones than my Nexus 5).

Answer (score 15):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

`getWindow` is a method defined for activities, and won't require you to find a `View` first.

Comment: Same as @hackbod's solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2134602/435605

Answer (score 12):

Adding  `android:keepScreenOn="true"` in the XML of the activity(s) you want to keep the screen on is the best option. Add that line to the main layout of the activity(s).

Something like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use [`setKeepScreenOn()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29) from the View class.

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple ways you can do it:

Solution 1:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);    
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

In activity_main.xml file, simply add:

```
<android:KeepScreenOn="true"/>
```

My advice: please don't use WakeLock. If you use it, you have to define extra permission, and mostly this thing is useful in CPU's development environment.

Also, make sure to turn off the screen while closing the activity. You can do it in this way:

```
public void onDestry() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Comment: There are such suggestions/answers exist already

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [Power Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) to acquire a wake lock in your application.

Most probably you are interested in a [FULL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
....
wl.release();
```

Comment: he's talking about screen (can be solved with one flag), why did you suggest FULL_WAKE_LOCK?

Answer (score 4):

No need to add permission and do tricks. Just use below text in your main layout.

```
  android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point method

```
final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        this.mWakeLock.acquire();
```

is deprecated.

You should use
`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` and `getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`