# How keep the screen on while the activity is in the foreground?

Tags: android

Please I need to to keep the screen on while my activity is in the foreground.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442079/keep-the-screen-awake-throughout-my-activity?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use: `keepScreenOn` and `setKeepScreenOn()`.

Please see this [link](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/22/letting-device-sleep-intelligently.html)

Answer (score 1):

Acquire a [Wake Lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) or add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to any of the Views used in that Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this line in your onCreate() method:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that its contents has a View that has set its `keepScreenOn` field/attribute to `true`.