# Abnormal app crash after screen dimming

Tags: android

Well it has been great starting android apps development.
But heres something new that happened now!
**After the user shows no activity, The app is getting forceclosed by the OS**
Something that it is famous for...
Now this only happens to this screen n not the Main Activity screen
**I have used ListView for this Playlist Activity**

Now - I want to allow screen dimming, n not Disable it!Whilst keeping the app in memory!
Plz could any one tell how

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    ListView playlistView = (ListView)findViewById(R.string.playlistHolder);
    String[] STAR = { "*" };        
        Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(allsongsuri, STAR, selection, null, null);
        File musicstorage = new File("assets/music.xml");
     // Create the array list of to do items
            ArrayList<String> playItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            // Create the array adapter to bind the array to the listview
            ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
            aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,playItems);
            // Bind the array adapter to the listview.
            playlistView.setAdapter(aa);
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String song_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                    String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                    String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                    int album_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                    String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                    int artist_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
                    playItems.add(0, song_name);
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: show us your code and the error

Comment: there is no error as such n well the app runs good unless and until the screen is lit!! seems like some memory efficiency program does, but still am uploading the code stand by!

Comment: Posting the logcat from a crashed run would also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442079/keep-the-screen-awake-throughout-my-activity) . Also, for wakelocks, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html. In particular, `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` may be enough depending upon your needs. As to why the app force closes, post a Logcat *and* the relevant code portion.