# Android: Starting Activity as Intent activates WakeLock. How to disable this behavior?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, wakelock

In an Android-app I load an Activity as Intent:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startApp();
    }
    private void startApp() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewLoader.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

With this code, a "WakeLock" starts - the app does not go to sleep-mode again. I can see the WakeLock clear with the console-command:

```
adb shell dump sys power
```

Dump:

```
Wake Locks: size=1
  SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK        'WindowManager' ON_AFTER_RELEASE (uid=1000, pid=386, ws=WorkSource{10085})

Suspend Blockers: size=4
  PowerManagerService.WakeLocks: ref count=1
  PowerManagerService.Display: ref count=1
  PowerManagerService.Broadcasts: ref count=0
  PowerManagerService.WirelessChargerDetector: ref count=0
```

How can I deactivate this WakeLock?

If I uncomment the line "startActivity(i);" in the code-example above, no WakeLock is given (expected behavior). So somehow the starting of the Activty starts also a WakeLock. By the way: I have no WakeLock feature in the loaded Activity as well. It's basically a WebView-Loader with some async JavaScript-calls...

Comment: probably the problem is in the WebViewLoader activity, not the way you start it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11759222

I had set a flag in my layout-file by accident: android:keepScreenOn="true". I set it to false and sleep mode is coming back!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following permission from the `Manifest.xml` file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: If your doesn't use this permission then your application can't perform `WakeLock` functionality...may be its causing for other application.