# Force device to keep screen working

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to force device not to sleep, if my app is shown on the screen? Does manifest.xml have a special attribute for this?

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442079/keep-the-screen-awake-throughout-my-activity) help?

Comment: Check you answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11759222/2936153

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

or use tag in manifest

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Read
[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

Answer (score 0):

add this tag to your manifest file under activity tag
**android:keepScreenOn="true"**