# how to keep screen on for an specific duration?

Tags: android, android-activity

in one of my `Activities` I want to keep screen on for 2 minutes (e.g.). I know I can keep screen on with:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

but how to do that for an specific duration ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I keep the screen on in my App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app)

Comment: Is there an app that does just that? I'm looking for such a functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many ways to clear flags after 2 minutes..like you can use timer or thread or handler

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }, 20000);
```

in this way you can clear the flags

Answer (score 1):

Take this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // turn screen off function
        }
    }, 2000);
```

After 2sec it will turn off the screen. You just have to put the turn off function in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(); 
 // run a thread after 2 seconds to start the home screen
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                // start your screen  
            }
        }, 2000); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until the run() method will be called
```