# Error while creating .aab in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio 4.0.1. When I want to convert my application to .aab format, I get the following error. What should I do?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=false, dexing-min-sdk=17, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\8ae7b36524b4d2df17c0bae7e36de153\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                                  

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: does this answer you question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

in onCreate()