# How to implement a always on display in android application?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement always on display for a music visualizer application. What is the best way to that ?

I've tried full screen intent to unlock screen on lock screen but I don't think it was designed for this use case

Comment: Do you mean, how to not get a lock screen while running the app?

Comment: Maybe it's a duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app